# T-SQL How to combine multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've googled pretty much everything I can think of and haven't been able to find a solution that fits my needs. It's pretty simple in theory: I need to combine multiple rows of a result set by their member code. The values for the price columns will always be identical per member code and there will only be one price% value per member code.

Table

```
|Member_Code|price 1|price 1%|price 2|price 2%|
|      eeeee|     15|      10|     20|       0|
|      eeeee|     15|       0|     20|      50|
```

Result I need

```
|Member_Code|price 1|price 1%|price 2|price 2%|
|      eeeee|     15|      10|     20|      50|
```

My table contains 60000 records so I can't just do

```
select max(column) where member_code = x
```

The sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f084/1

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY Member_Code` with `MAX` aggregate function on Price columns will help

```
select 
[Member_Code], 
max([Price List 1]),
max([Price List 1%]),
max([Price List 2]), 
max([Price List 2%]), 
max([Price List 3]),
max([Price List 3%])
from Table1 
group by [Member_Code]
```

Comment: Thank you! will accept your answer shorlty. i tried this option but only put max on the % colums which of course failed